# Is it possible to re-generate Lucene index in background?

Tags: indexing, lucene, compass-lucene

Sometimes there is need to re-generate a lucene index, e.g. when something changes in the Compass mapping or in the way boosts are applied, or if something went corrupt for whatever reason.

In my case, generation of the index takes about 5 to 6 hours, clearing the index before leads to data not being complete for this interval. I. e. doing a search in this time returns an incomplete result.

Is there any standard way to have lucene generate the index in the background? E.g. write index to a temporary directory and (when indexing is finished without exceptions etc) replace the existing index with the new one?

Of course, one could implement this "manually", but does one have to? Sounds like a common use case to me.

Best regards + Thanks for your opinion,

Peter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar experience; there were certain parameters to the Analyzer which would get changed from time to time; obviously if that was the case, the entire index needs to get rebuilt. (I won't go into the details, suffice to say I had the same requirement!)

I did what you suggested in your question. There were three directories, "old", "current" and "new". Queries from the live site went against "current" always. The index recreation process was:

1. Recursive delete on the "old" and "new" directories
2. Create the new index into the "new" directory (in my case takes about 6 hrs)
3. Rename "current" to "old"; and "new" to "current"
4. Recursive delete the "old" directory

An analysis of what happens when the process crashes - if it crashes in the 1st step, the next time it will just carry on. If it crashes in the 2nd step then the "new" directory will get deleted next run. The 3rd step is very fast - renaming a directory is fast and atomic. Crashing in the 4th step doesn't matter, it'll just get cleaned up next run.

The careful observer will note that in step 3, the system could crash between renaming the current directory away and moving the new directory in. This is unlikely to happen as directory rename is so fast. The system has been in production for a few years and this has never happened (yet?).

Answer (score 0):

I think the usual way to do this is to use solr's replication functionality. In your case though, the master and slave would be on the same machine, but just pointed at different directories.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem. Our data is indexed in Lucene, but the original source is DB and content repo.

So if an index goes out of sync (or data type changes, etc.), we simply iterate over all existing entries in the index and re-generate the data so each document gets updated. It is not really a complex thing to do.